# Getting Image URL in Views with field_views_field

Tags: 7, views, theming

I have an content type called Image that has two fields:  Title and Image

I have a Views block created so that it displays the images I want based on my criteria.

What I need is to have the raw image URL available.

```
Example:

/sites/default/files/background1.jpg
```

I found this article [Rendering Drupal 7 fields (the right way)](https://www.computerminds.co.uk/articles/rendering-drupal-7-fields-right-way) and quite frankly, I am at a loss.

From the [Drupal API](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21field%21field.module/group/field/7):

```
field_view_field($entity_type, $entity, $field_name, $display = array(), $langcode = NULL)
```

I know I have to code the views-view-fields--my_custom_view.tpl.php, but everything I do results in an error.

What needs to go in this file so that I can simply get the URL from the image that I am looking for?

Also  point in the right direction to a tutorial would be great.  Everything I have found assumes you are an expert in Drupal and at this point, everything feels circular.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was able to do this strictly using Views by creating a relationship to the File Entity.

I have detailed this in another post which can be found here [Getting the URL from an Image (or Any File)](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/177531/extracting-uri-value-from-image-in-views-getting-index-error/177626#177626).

This eliminates the need for a URL Formatter module and is D8 compatible out of the box.

Comment: This works, but I have a problem with versioning: now the relationship with the file collects all the files in the version history, not just the current published revision. So I end up with lots of duplicates for each node. Any idea how to go around this? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

[Image URL Formatter](https://www.drupal.org/project/image_url_formatter)

> This module add a url formatter for image field. Then you can output
>   image url directly.
>
> Most of the code, maybe more than 90%, is just copy from the drupal
>   core. I think it is stable enough.
>
> I have created a content type, and add an image field instance to it,
>   later i use views to export the data of this content type.And i want
>   to output the data,then i could import it into another drupal 7 site
>   with feeds module. What i need is the url of the image field, but i
>   could not export the image url directly. That is why i create this
>   small module.
>
> **Usage**
>
> (1)After install this module,then you add an image field,then you can
>   goto this bundle's manage display page,here at format column,you can
>   choose "Image URL" instead of "Image".
>
> (2)When you add an image field in your views,then you config the
>   Formatter for this field, here you can choose "Image URL" instead of
>   "Image".
>
> Then you can output image's URL instead of Image itself.

Comment: Thanks, I might use this as a last resort, but I am really trying to do this without loading another module.  After all, it's only going to be used on one page.

Comment: Solved it.  See my answer.